# Error on git clone in cygwin: error: inflate: data stream error (invalid code lengths set)

Tags: git, cygwin

I am trying to clone a repository using git on cygwin.

Machine is a Windows XP machine, running a newly updated version of cygwin

I have cloned this repository without any trouble previously, but on a new machine I get this issue:

```
buildmeister@winbuild /cygdrive/d
$ git clone git@github.com:gollumullog/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
Receiving objects: 100remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid code lengths set)
error: failed to read object 14007e4054f6c7c33e03975c480ba9986510d4ff at offset 12 from /cygdrive/d/test/.git/objects/pa
ck/pack-ad4395202f65ea50c9cef2e4fc4a5d9cca8321bc.pack
fatal: packed object 14007e4054f6c7c33e03975c480ba9986510d4ff (stored in /cygdrive/d/test/.git/objects/pack/pack-ad43952
02f65ea50c9cef2e4fc4a5d9cca8321bc.pack) is corrupt
```

The above repository is just a stub I created on github with only a readme file in it.

Any help diagnosing the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Notes:
- I have seen some weird permission issues on this machine, and wonder if this is related: ie I create a folder using explorer in windows, and the permissions set appear to be d---------+ when I examine in cygwin, but I can cd to it, and create files in it, etc.